# Programm to switch Tabs in a Browser with Start and Pause Button

Tags: powershell

got a question.
I got a Whiteboard (Samsung Flip) and want it to start in the morning a bit before everyone starts working. It is supposed to have a few Tabs that it changes and reloads every x seconds. One site will be our ticketsystem and I want to have an always on top window with a start and a stop button, so i can stop the tabbing, work on the Whiteboard, and then go back to the tabbing once i am done. I do not care if its pausing and resuming, or starting and stopping, as long as the Form with those buttons will be always on top. The Whiteboard wont have keyboard and mouse.
I build a powershell script that more or less does what it is supposed to do, but its not reliable. Whenever I run the script through ISE it sometimes works, sometimes not. For the part that is not working its simply the form that should be on top. Sometimes it doesnt appear at all, sometimes its not on top. I have to stop the script, restart ISE and then it works again. I also made a batch that starts the scripts with

`Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File c:\scripts\tabchanger.ps1`

Both the PC, that is connected to the Whiteboard, and the one I made this script on have the same structure with c:\scripts, and on my PC it works, it starts normally as it should with the form on top, and on the PC connected to the Whiteboard it is not loading the form.
Read a lot of bad stuff about DoEvents so I assume that that is the culprit. I am not a programmer so I dont even know how to do that without powershell, can anyone recommend me something? Like do it in Java instead of powershell. Would be a lot of work to get started with those since I have no programming experience but what can you do. Same with powershell, I just know what i found after googling around.

In case someone is interested in the powershell script and finds a fix then that would be the best.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  #laden von benötigten Daten 

#Edge starten mit den gewünschten Tabs. Ist ein weiteres mal für Button 3 Konfiguriert und muss da auch angepasst werden.
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://a.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://b.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://c.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://d.de

#Zeiger auf das Objekt, für den Fokuswechsel auf Edge
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

#Hauptfenster der Buttons
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{TopMost=$true}
$main_form.ClientSize        = '500,150'              # Breite x Höhe
$main_form.FormBorderStyle   = 'FixedDialog'          # Feste Fenstergröße
$main_form.topmost           = $true                  # Fenster immer im Vordergrund
$main_form.toplevel          = $true                  # Fenster immer im Vordergrund
$main_form.StartPosition     = "manual"               # Fenster Start Position auf Manuell setzen 
$main_form.Location          = "455,795"            # Fenster Start Position Breite, Höhe
$main_form.MinimizeBox       = $False                 # Minimieren entfernen
$main_form.MaximizeBox       = $False                 # Maximieren entfernen
```

The Whiteboard has a higher resolution, i just removed 1 number for both x and y coordinates, so it would be shown normally on any screen.

```
# Button Start
$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Text       = "Start"                       #angezeigter Text
$Button1.Size       = "110,60"                      #Größe: Länge x Breite
$Button1.Location   = "20,10"                       #Position beim Starten
$main_form.Controls.Add($Button1)

# Button Cancel
$Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button    
$Button2.Text       = "Stop"                        #angezeigter Text
$Button2.Size       = "110,60"                      #Größe: Länge x Breite
$Button2.Location   = "140,10"                      #Position beim Starten
$Button2.Enabled    = $false                        #Knopf am Anfang ausgegraut
$main_form.Controls.Add($Button2)


# Button Edge
$Button3= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button    
$Button3.Text       = "Edge"                        #angezeigter Text
$Button3.Size       = "110,60"                      #Größe: Länge x Breite
$Button3.Location   = "260,10"                      #Position beim Starten
$Button3.Enabled    = $true                         #Knopf am Anfang ausgegraut
$main_form.Controls.Add($Button3)


# Status Text
$LbStatus = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LbStatus.Text      = "......"
$LbStatus.Font      = '5'
$LbStatus.size      = "350,60"
$LbStatus.Location  = "20,80"
$main_form.Controls.Add($LbStatus)

#der "Tab wechseln und Seite neu laden" Job
$jobScript = {   
    while($true)         #läuft immer
    {
    #wartet 5 Sekunden, sendet dann strg + tab, um den Tab zu wechseln, und nach einer weiteren Sekunde wird die Seite neu geladen
    Start-Sleep 30           
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^{TAB}');
    Start-Sleep 1
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F5}');
}
}



#Aktionen, die beim Klicken des ersten Buttons ausgeführt werden
$Button1.Add_Click(
{
    $Button1.Enabled    = $False                    #Start-Button wird ausgegraut
    $Button2.Enabled    = $true                     #Stop-Button wird wieder als benutzbar gesetzt
    $Button3.Enabled    = $False                    #Edge-Button wird ausgegraut
    $wshell.AppActivate('edge')                     #Setzt Edge als aktives Fenser
    $LbStatus.Text      = "Wechselt Tabs"
    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $jobScript        #Startet den Tab-Changer Job 

    #führt den Job aus, bis er fertig wird, reagiert jedoch auf weitere Events
    Do {[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()} Until ($job.State -ne "Running")
    $LbStatus.Text      = $job.State   
    $Button1.Enabled    = $true
    $Button2.Enabled    = $false    
    $Button3.Enabled    = $true

}
)

#Tab wechseln beenden
$Button2.Add_Click({
Stop-Job -Job $job
$LbStatus.Text = $job.state
$Button1.Enabled = $false
$Button2.Enabled = $false
$Button3.Enabled = $true

})

$Button3.Add_Click({
#Edge starten mit den gewünschten Tabs
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://a.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://b.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://c.de
Start-Process microsoft-edge:https://d.de

#Zeiger auf das Objekt, für den Fokuswechsel auf Edge
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

#wartet, bis Edge offen ist und drückt dann F11 für Vollbild
Start-Sleep 2
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{F11}');
})


$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: btw, if i start the script via ISE it works, if i use the batch the form somewhat loads. The taskbar shows an powershell icon, but if i hover with the mouse over it its simply empty. if i start the script via ISE it shows the buttons, that are configurated. And well this problem only happens on the PC that is connected to the Whiteboard, could it be that some GPO restrictions are messing with the script? Not sure if that could be it, since i can start it normaly through ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the issue. First of all, normal Powershell and ISE load different Assemblys, so they work differently. That translates to a Problem with the combination of pixel location and windows scaling, which was set to 300% on the Whiteboard as default. thats why I could use

`$main_form.StartPosition     = "manual"`
`$main_form.Location          = "455,795"`

each alone, while location doesnt do anything without the StartPosition set to manual and manual doesnt do anything without a set location. Both together doesnt work. You see the form appear as a window in the bar on the bottom but it doesnt appear on the screen.
I found the tip about scaling here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/aw62vb/windowsformsform_draws_different_in_ise_than_it/

After changing the scaling and adjusting the location it worked as i wanted.